# Why does the while loop creating my game's animation sequence seem to be ignored?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an online game based off the game Simon. The problem is that I want the site to show the entire pattern every round, but for some reason, it's only showing the newest addition to the pattern.

My current code is(the important part is the JS):

```js
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];

var started = false;
var level = 0;

$(document).keypress(function() {
  if (!started) {
    $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
    nextSequence();
    started = true;
  }
});

$(".btn").click(function() {

  var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);

  playSound(userChosenColor);
  animatePress(userChosenColor);

  checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length-1);
});

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {

    if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
      if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length){
        setTimeout(function () {
          nextSequence();
        }, 1000);
      }
    } else {
      playSound("wrong");
      $("body").addClass("game-over");
      $("#level-title").text("Game Over, Press Any Key to Restart");

      setTimeout(function () {
        $("body").removeClass("game-over");
      }, 200);

      startOver();
    }
}


function nextSequence() {
  userClickedPattern = [];
  level++;
  $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);

  var i = 0;
  while (gamePattern.length < i) {
    $("#" + gamePattern[i]).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(gamePattern[i]);
    i++;
  }
 
  $("#" + randomChosenColor).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  playSound(randomChosenColor);
}

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 100);
}

function playSound(name) {
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}

function startOver() {
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  started = false;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin:  5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;

}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div lass="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I think this is the part of the code that is the problem:

```js
var i = 0;
      while (gamePattern.length < i) {
        $("#" + gamePattern[i]).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
        playSound(gamePattern[i]);
        i++;
      }
```

What is happening?

Comment: Can you try and isolate your problem more? Instead of dropping the entire code.

Comment: An array's length will never be less than 0.

Answer (score 1):

you have posted a couple hundred lines of code without any clear explanation of what is wrong and what is happening. however, one thing for sure, this code will never execute:

```
var i = 0;
while (gamePattern.length < i)....
```

because an array can never be less than 0 in length.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop condition is written backwards.

Try this:

```
  while (i < gamePattern.length) {
    $("#" + gamePattern[i]).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    playSound(gamePattern[i]);
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: This works, thanks! While using this I now realize there is anther problem, but I can fix that one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> ```
> 1 var i = 0;
> 2 while (gamePattern.length < i) {
> 3   $("#" + gamePattern[i]).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
> 4   playSound(gamePattern[i]);
> 5   i++;
> 6 }
> ```

The comparison is incorrect, as someone else noted, so the loop won't run at all.

But if you fix that, there are other problems, which are trickier.

In line 3, jQuery sets up a fade in-out-in for the pattern.
Line 3 simply sets this up, using `setTimeout()` or similar internally.
Line 3 **does not wait** for the fades to complete, it simply schedules them and moves to line 4.

**Scheduled actions only occur once your code is finished running, and are run by the browser event loop**.

So in line 4, the sound is requested, but the actions in line 3 are incomplete.
That may make the sounds appear "early".

And the worst part, lines 5-6 causes us to loop back to line 3 to do the same thing with a new pattern and sound.  **This is bad because we are asking for more patterns and sounds and the first patterns and sounds have not actually been run yet. They have only been scheduled, and will only run when your code is "done".** The result will be that you will probably only see one of the patterns, probably the final request.

One way out of this nasty coding trap is to use `setTimeout()` and recursion in a custom function.

```
// untested
function action(patterns, sounds, index, interval){ 
   if (index<patterns.length){ 
      $("#" + patterns[index]).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
      setTimeout(playSounds, 100, sounds[index]); // or 200 or 300 to align sound and display
      setTimeout(action, interval, patterns, sounds, index+1, interval);
   } else {
      // code to execute when action is done
   }

}
action(gamePattern, gamePattern, 0, 300);
// note: action returns immediately.  If you need something to run after
action, then we should that code to the else block
```